# How long is your class?

Tags: word-usage

I need to ask someone how long does their class take time to be finished. How should I say it and which one of the following sentences is idiomatic in English language?

> a) How long does your class take? 
>   b) How long does your class take time? 
>   c) How long does your class last?

Bringing up this question I'm going to realize the correct usage and semantic nuance of the verbs "take" and "last".

Comment: You can try these: *"How long is your class?"* *"How long will your class last?"* *"How long will your class take?"*

Comment: Hi @DamkerngT. But I do disagree. As you mentioned in you offered examples, 'last' and 'take' mean the same thing, while as far as I am concerned they do not (at least in this particular context)! So I wonder if someone could help me more. :)

Comment: I'm sorry if my offers cannot fulfill your requirements. One thing I want to mention is that *last* does not exactly mean *take* (though obviously they are related). Again, I'm sorry if my comment makes it sound so. Also, because I can't really know your context precisely enough (someone would be able to, I'm sure), my suggestions are simply common phrases used in general occasions.

Comment: I personally think b) is odd, since we don't usually use *how long* with *time*, but *how much* e.g. *How much time does your class take?*

Comment: I've deleted some comments. Let's please all remember to be polite to each other in comments, and try not to use them for too much extended discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take and Last are used to talk about the time necessary for something

**Take** is generally used when we are in control of the action and it suggests more active involvement:
My homework  normally takes me one hour everyday.

**Last** is generally used to talk about the duration of something and implies a more passive experience:
The lessons in the school last 45 minutes each.
The movie lasts 2 hours.
So, sentence 'C' is correct. With "take" you could ask: "How long does it usually take you to translate three pages?" Sentence "b" is wrong.

Comment: It was really helpful @Vic. I got the point. ;)

Comment: Just one more question. I would be thankful if you could answer this question too. Which one would be natural in this context and why:
A: Can I talk to Steve?
B: Could you please hold the line? Hes' on another call.
A: Sure
B: Thank you for holding sir. I think that it's going to (take / last) a while.

Comment: "I think that it's going to take a while." "take a while"  is used when a task may take a long time to complete.

Comment: @A-friend strange...what makes my answer good for downvoting! Option 'c' is correct, my very first line! option 'b' is out is also mentioned!

Comment: Dear @MaulikV I do not understand what you are trying to say! Could you please clarify what's your intention? :(

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way of telling that is the option *(c)*

> *(c)* - How long does your class last? - it **clearly** asks for the time/period--say 2 hr.

The *intransitive verb* 'last' is used exactly this way to mean something that continues for a particular period of time. [OALD defines it on this page here (#1)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/last_4) with an example of *How long does the play last?*.

Having this said, the option *(a)* uses the word *take* for no reason and it might be considered as redundant if we stick to OALD's use of that phrase.

The option *(b)* is also out for the same reason. In fact, it even uses an extra word *time*.

Worth noting is Damkerng's comment that says *How long is your class?*, which also seems a correct usage.

> [long (adj-#4)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/long_1) - used for asking or talking about particular periods of time 
>   ~ *How long is the course?* **and** *How long a stay did you have in mind?*

Comment: Hi @MaulikV and thank you for the response. But my native Australian friend says me it is not possible to say that or at least it is not the way we say it. While I was thinking exactly like you my friend. Unfortunately I think there is something wrong with our common thought. :(

Comment: what is it not possible to say that?

Comment: Choice 'C' is not possible. But he is not a linguist or someone who is a lot into lingual discussions. He just said it would be wrong to say that. Both 'a' and 'c'. But I didn't ask him about my choice 'b'. Is it clear now? ;)

Comment: @A-friend If choice *c* is not possible according to him, surely he's a linguist challenging OALD! :) All the best.

Comment: I think C is possible but it's not what I'd personally choose to say.  (I think the string "class last" sounds just a little bit silly.)

Comment: Thanks @snailplane. I was wondering if you tell me how a native would say it?

Comment: Personally, I'd say "How long is your class?", just like you wrote in the title.

Comment: And how long will be your class (when you need to ask about the future). Right?

Comment: No, SAI only moves *will* before *your class*.  *Be* remains after it: "How long will your class be?"